# Gitデプロイに関する権限設定について

Tags: git

いつもお世話になっています。
サーバーの勉強を始めたばかりの初心者です。

先日、ユーザーのグループとパーミッション問題で躓き、こちらで助けて頂いたのですが、別途同様の疑問が発生しまして、再度質問させていただく事にしました。
初歩的な質問かもしれません。申し訳ありません。

【前提】
・Git環境構築のため、『git』ユーザを作成した
・『/var/lib/git/test.git』にリモートリポジトリを作成している
・Git環境を用意するまでは『admin』アカウントでFTPを行っていた

【やりたい事】
・上記リモートリポジトリを公開領域『/var/www/html/test/』にデプロイしたい
・同時に公開領域にFTPも出来るようにしたい

【過程】
リモートリポジトリへのローカルからのPush、またリモートリポジトリからの公開領域へのCloneは問題なく行えています。
『/var/lib/git/test.git/hooks/post-receive』への記述は

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/html/test
git --git-dir=.git pull
echo test >/tmp/test.log
```

となっており、最後のechoは動作確認用に入れていますが、出力されているのでpost-receiveは実行されているのではないか…と思っています。

【疑問】
FTPとGitデプロイ両方、と言うのは難しいのでしょうか？
色々とユーザグループ設定やchown、chmod等試してみたのですが、思うようにいかずに困っています。
gitユーザをadminユーザに加えて（usermod -aG admin git）、公開領域のフォルダを775、ファイルを664にし、所有者設定はgit:adminにする事でFTPは出来たのですが、デプロイがされていないようです。

正常にデプロイされるためには、どのような設定にすべきなんでしょうか？
権限周りの事をきちんと理解できておらず、本当に申し訳ありません。

Comment: post-receiveを使ったpush時の自動デプロイを、FTPでアップロードした場合にも作動させたいということですか？

Comment: `post-receive` の pull の部分を `git --git-dir=.git pull 2>/tmp/test_err.log` としてみるのはどうでしょうか。何かエラーが発生しているのであれば `/tmp/test_err.log` にそのエラーの内容が記録される事になります。

Comment: unariau様　いえ、同時作動ではなく、デプロイ先になっている公開領域に、別途必要な時にFTP操作も手動で出来るようにしたいです。権限かパーミッションの設定がまずいのか、両方というのが巧く行かず…。

Comment: metropolis様　アドバイスありがとうございます。エラー内容の出力勉強になります。ただいま出先ですので、後程試してみます！

Comment: metropolis様　帰宅後早速試してみました。お陰でPullでどんなエラーが発生しているか確認することができ、そこからエラーを調べて解決することが出来ました。ありがとうございました！

Comment: @ritsu 問題が解決したのであれば、どのように確認してどのように修正したのか、を回答として投稿していただけると、今後ここにたどり着いた人への助けになります。

Comment: エラーを見て気付いたのですが、Gitで管理されているところにFTPしてしまうと、管理されていないファイルが入って来ておかしくなるよな、そうだよな……と言う事に気付きました。手探りでやるとこうなるので駄目ですね。

Answer (score 2):

たとえば、この[本家の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315413/git-fails-to-push-to-ftp-server)を見ていると、 git は、 ftp で git レポジトリを公開する場合には、そのレポジトリは基本的に readonly で動作させる想定の様子です。(clone はできる、 push はできない)

そもそも OP は FTP でレポジトリへの更新操作を行うことを想定して、この質問を作成した様子でしたが、それはちょっとあまりうまく動作しなさそうだ、と最後には自己解決した模様です。